# How to handle updates in the right way using signalr?

Tags: c#, angular, signalr

I have a client application `Angular` and a `signalR` hub, and also I have a service that take a timestamp as a parameter.

I want to invoke a method in the hub when I press on a start button in the client, and when the method is invoked I want to keep listing to all the changes (create a timer) until the client press on the stop button then I will stop the timer.

So I want to ask which is better:

1- Call the invoked method from the client with time stamp and then create a `setInterval` to call the method in it and when the stop button is pressed I can stop it.

**Pros:**
It is easy to start and stop the timer.

**Cons:**
I am invoking the method each 1 sec, and then I am checking on the client if there are response to update the UI.

2- Invoke the method once and then create a timer for each client on the server and when the client press on stop button I can invoke another method to stop the timer for that client.

**Pros:**
I am checking the timestamp in the hub and I will send the data to the client only if the timeStamp from the service > timeStamp locally

**Cons:**
I actually don't know how to create a timer for each client, *so if this is the right way please help me*

Comment: Why use a timer at all? Just have the client listen for server notifications. SignalR eliminates the need for polling by pushing notifications to the client using websockets

Comment: I want to get the data each 1 second and the service take a time stamp because of that

Comment: Which means the *server* needs to send data to the client every 1 second. Which begs the question why - are you sending progress notification messages? Or just the time, which is a pretty expensive way to do this? For short durations, you could have an asynchronous action on the Hub with `await Task.Delay(1000);` and send responses every 1 second, or perhaps. use an Rx source. For longer jobs, you need to handle them appropriately, using eg BackgroundService, and call the hub every 1 second to send a notification

Comment: Why you need updates each second? If you send updates each second and don't present anything if there is no change is the same as if the server sends only messages when there is a change...

Comment: I have a service that don't change data dynamically and depend on a times stamp, so to get the updated data i need to call the service each time and then check the time stamps if it is greater, that is why i am sending requests each 1 sec, if there are any error with the approach please tell me

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what do you mean with `Rx source, BackgroundService` can you provide me with links.

Comment: Are you using .NET Old or .NET Core? The [SignalR streaming examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/streaming?view=aspnetcore-3.1#javascript-client) use what you describe to show various ways of creating a long/infinite stream of notifications

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to write part of your business logic on the client. Which is the wrong place to put it. It "feels" as though there's something wrong with the architecture. But I can't be sure from the available data. It's just a hunch.

Comment: No, I am asking for what is the right way to do things in order to avoid doing something that will affect the performance, because I want to create a page that can be open for long time and have sensitive data and every thing needs to be real time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `SignalR` for real time data communication. Invoking a method every second is just joking on the `SignalR` face... So this is not a solution.

The best solution would be using the group feature.

Example:

1. You start button will add the user to an group.
2. While your user is on the group it will receive all the data you need. `await this.Clients.Group("someGroup").BroadcastMessage(message);`
3. Your stop button will remove the user from the group so it will not receive data anymore.

Some code example on the hub:

```cs
public async Task Start()
{
    // Add user to the data group

    await this.Groups.AddToGroupAsync(this.Context.ConnectionId, "dataGroup");
}

public async Task Stop()
{
    // Add user to the data group

    await this.Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(this.Context.ConnectionId, "dataGroup");
}
```

Worker example that sends data to the users that pressed start and receive real time data.

```cs
private readonly IHubContext<SignalRHub, ISignalRHub> hub;

private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

public Worker(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IHubContext<SignalRHub, ISignalRHub> hub)
{
    this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    this.hub = hub;
}

protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await this.hub.Clients.Group("dataGroup").BroadcastMessage(DataManager.GetData());

        this.Logger.LogDebug("Sent data to all users at {0}", DateTime.UtcNow);

        await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

PS: Where you have the worker, I assume you have some manager that gets the data or something to be sent to the user.

**Edit:** If you don't want to user worker, you can always just the timer like:

```cs
public class TimerManager
{
    private Timer _timer;
    private AutoResetEvent _autoResetEvent;
    private Action _action;
    public DateTime TimerStarted { get; }

    public TimerManager(Action action)
    {
        _action = action;
        _autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        _timer = new Timer(Execute, _autoResetEvent, 1000, 2000);
        TimerStarted = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public void Execute(object stateInfo)
    {
        _action();
        if((DateTime.Now - TimerStarted).Seconds > 60)
        {
            _timer.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it somewhere like:

```cs
 var timerManager = new TimerManager(() => this.hub.Clients.Group("dataGroup").BroadcastMessage(DataManager.GetData()));
```

Comment: i was reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio, so is using `timer` is different than `workers`?

Comment: @Kardon63 you can use timer as well, I will update the answer with time example, but I believe the worker will do better job but it is up to you what will fit better to your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Option #1 isn't available since SignalR exists to remove the need for polling. Frequent polling doesn't scale either. If every client polled the server every 1 second, the web site would end up paying a *lot* of CPU and bandwidth for nothing. Business people don't like frequent polling either, as all hosters and cloud providers charge for egress.

The [SignalR streaming examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/streaming?view=aspnetcore-3.1) use timed notifications as a simple example of streaming notifications using `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`. In the simplest example, a counter increments every `delay` milliseconds :

```
public class AsyncEnumerableHub : Hub
{
    public async IAsyncEnumerable<int> Counter(
        int count,
        int delay,
        [EnumeratorCancellation]
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            // Check the cancellation token regularly so that the server will stop
            // producing items if the client disconnects.
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            yield return i;

            // Use the cancellationToken in other APIs that accept cancellation
            // tokens so the cancellation can flow down to them.
            await Task.Delay(delay, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

The client can call this action passing the desired delay and just start receiving notifications. SignalR knows this is a stream of notifications because it returns `IAsyncEnumerable`.

The next, more advanced example uses [Channels](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/) to allow the publisher method `WriteItemsAsync` to send a stream of notifications to the hub.

The action itself is simpler, it just returns the Channel's reader:

```
public ChannelReader<int> Counter(
    int count,
    int delay,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<int>();

    // We don't want to await WriteItemsAsync, otherwise we'd end up waiting 
    // for all the items to be written before returning the channel back to
    // the client.
    _ = WriteItemsAsync(channel.Writer, count, delay, cancellationToken);

    return channel.Reader;
}
```

The publisher method writes to the `ChannelWriter` instead of returning an `IAsyncEnumerable` :

```
private async Task WriteItemsAsync(
    ChannelWriter<int> writer,
    int count,
    int delay,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Exception localException = null;
    try
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            await writer.WriteAsync(i, cancellationToken);

            // Use the cancellationToken in other APIs that accept cancellation
            // tokens so the cancellation can flow down to them.
            await Task.Delay(delay, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        localException = ex;
    }

    writer.Complete(localException);
}
```

This method can easily be in a different class. All that's needed is to pass `ChannelWriter` to the publisher.

Comment: i am a lit bit of confused on when to use `streams` vs `timers`, I think wen need to just stream data for long pooling and don't care about groups or connection ids then it is the right way to use `streams`?